# How to use Ant to auto renaming output apk file?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant

I'm currently playing with Ant to do some auto branding work. I modified default build.xml and setup my own target. What I hope to ask is that is there a way in Ant Script that could automatic renaming the apk file just build with the certain name?

I currently has this Ant target setup in my build.xml:

```
<target name="release-brandA"
            depends="default, -set-release-mode, -release-obfuscation-check, -package, -post-package, -release-prompt-for-password, -release-nosign, -release-sign, -post-build"
            description="Builds the application in release mode for brandA.">
    <delete dir="${res}" />
    <copydir dest="${res}" src="${branding}/brandA" forceoverwrite="ture" />
    <replaceregexp flags="g" byline="false">
        <regexp pattern="import com.arthur.android(.*).R;"/>
        <substitution expression="import com.arthur.android.brandA.R;"/>
        <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.java" />
    </replaceregexp>
    <replaceregexp flags="g" byline="false">
        <regexp pattern="package=&quot;com.arthur.android(.*)&quot;" />
        <substitution expression="package=&quot;com.arthur.android.brandA&quot;" />
        <fileset dir="" includes="AndroidManifest.xml" />
    </replaceregexp>
</target>
```

Is there a way that I could add some more task, to let the output file just be like brandA.apk?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The final apk filename is actually defined by the property 'out.final.file'

So you could create a new Task that sets this property:

```
<target name="-set-out-final-file">
    <property name="out.final.file" location="${out.absolute.dir}/brandA.apk" />
</target>
```

Finally, you just need to invoke the `-set-out-final-file` target before calling the debug or release targets.

Using your `release-brandA` task, it would become this:

```
<target name="release-brandA"
        depends="default, -set-out-final-file, -set-release-mode, -release-obfuscation-check...
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blog.matoski.com/articles/generating-filename-based-on-the-android-project-name-and-version-name-when-running-ant/) I found more better explanation and more suitable way to override release target.

Please refer to section:

```
<target
        name="release"
        depends="custom-set-release-mode, android_rules.release" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple.Refer this link [1]: https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html

So in the above case,we need to run it like this,

**ant debug -Dout.final.file=brandA.apk**

Thats it.